# Realtime chatroom - moderation and deleting certain messages - web sockets or REST in AWS?

Tags: websocket

Best practice for realtime chats seems to be web sockets. But what if I want to have a moderator who can delete certain messages for all users? Especially when all other users don't have to register but only choose name and start chatting. Is this a better job for REST than web sockets? Generally and specifically in implementing using AWS/Node?